# Angelcare baby monitor pad compatability with RPi

Tags: monitoring

I've got a 6 month old little girl and a raspberry pi on the way, we've got this wind-up baby mobile that lasts for maybe 2 minutes, but she just loves it and insists that we keep winding it up over and over and over again.

Originally I was going to make something video game related but figured a RPi powered baby monitor + mobile would be a good project. I've got an Angelcare brand baby monitor, with a vibration sensor pad. I would like to have my RPi call or text me or start up a webcam when the Angelcare monitor goes off, as well as power this baby mobile and play music (she loves radiohead)

I've got most of the hardware coming in the mail already but would need a low power motor that could slowly spin the mobile, there are plenty of tutorials for this however so I'm okay for that side of things.

How viable is a project like this and what am I looking at in terms of interfacing with the existing baby monitor. The pad connects with what looks like a 3.5mm audio plug, but I'm not against opening up the monitor itself and interfacing that way.